# Alternative, more commonly accepted parlance for "currentness"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

The following two sentences are identical:

> Ensure that X is current.
>
> Ensure the currentness of X.

However, the word "[currentness](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/current)", while present in the dictionary, represents a [very uncommon usage of the phrase](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+current%2Ccurrentness+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3). Are there any alternative ways to phrase this sentence while avoiding the "is current" construct?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The standard word is "currency". It doesn't just refer to money.

(In fact, the usage to refer to money comes from certain coinage being "current" in a certain locale, i.e. commonly accepted. Accordingly, Scottish notes, although not legal tender in England, are current.)

Comment: *Currency* is good, but there's also [topicality](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=topicality) which I often think is even more evocative of *"of particular importance right now"*. Things can still be *current* even if they've been popular for a long time, but usually if they're *topical* they're also relatively new.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Right - although I think 'topicality' implies a level of broad popularity.

Answer (score 8):

As Marcin notes, *currency* is usable here; one could say:

> Ensure the currency of X.

However, the following phrasings are more likely:

> Ensure that X is *[up to date](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/up-to-date)*. [or *up-to-date*]
>   Ensure that X is the latest version.
>   Ensure that X is current.

(where the latter is one of your examples.)  *[Current](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/current#Adjective)* as in *current events* usually has the sense "Existing or occurring at the moment", meaning now.  *[Contemporaneous](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/contemporaneous)*, on the other hand, means "Existing or created in the same period of time".  For example:

> Contemporaneous notes are preferred for documentation of incidents.

Answer (score 2):

Some alternatives could be:

Ensure that X is up-to-date.

or

Ensure that X is updated.

Answer (score 0):

I like currency, but many people won't understand this usage and currentness sounds awkward.  Perhaps use "relevant" ?

Comment: Or *relevance,* since a noun is required. But something can be relevant and yet not current.