# Term for Being Aware of New Things

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a term for being aware of new things, such as 'my ____(being aware of new) for music has increased since having used this new website'.

Comment: I don't have any answer that would fit neatly into your blank, but how do you feel about "This new website has really let me *keep current* on the music scene" (or "*keep current* on [pop] music", or whatever).

Comment: My newfound appreciation for music. My newfound knowledge of music.

Comment: I'm going to post this as a comment rather than an answer, because while it's supported by the dictionary definition of the word, no contemporary speaker would use it this way: "my musical *currency* has increased since I started to use ...". If you don't believe me, see this answer (which also offers "*topicality*"): http://english.stackexchange.com/a/53888/55623

Comment: Wouldn't it be fitting if this word could incorporate the notion of being "in tune"

Comment: You are *hip* to new music.

Comment: There is a word _up-to-dateness_ but it wouldn't fit to your example.

Answer (score 1):

You may use **awareness** or **knowledge**,

- My awareness in music has increased since having used this new website
- My knowledge of music has increased since having used this new website
- I am up to date about music since, I started using this website.

Answer (score 0):

Trendiness: the quality of being up to date or very fashionable.

The word "trendiness" comes from "trendy" meaning very fashionable or up to date.

The source is Oxford online dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I think [receptivity](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Receptiveness) may suggest the idea of being aware and open to new things:

receptive:

> - open to arguments, ideas, or change; "receptive to reason and the logic of facts."
> - capable of or qualified for receiving.
> - ready or willing to receive favorably: receptive to their proposals.

Source:http://www.thefreedictionary.com/receptive

Answer (score 0):

**Awareness** is good in the exact same context as your sentence; you could also try **consciousness**, such as

> I've been more music-conscious since having used the website.

or

> I've been more conscious of music since having used the website.

Answer (score 0):

I [personally] would use adaptation, though everyone else's comments and answers are equally valid.

Answer (score -1):

Awakening, you might have to change the wording a bit but I think it works in context.

Comment: This answer would be improved if you provided a cited reference to a dictionary definition and explained a bit more why you think it fits the context.